# Form_tag url based on select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like it should be easy but not clear from the api doc how to mkae it work:

I have a form with a collection_select:

```
<%=form_tag(project_path) do %>
    <%= select_tag(:project_name, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, :id, :name))%>
    <%= submit_tag("Go") %>
  <% end %>
```

What I want to do here is navigate to the show action of the for the project selected when the user presses the "Go" button created by the submit tag.

the problem with the above code is that I can't figure out how to get the selected :id into the url when the user presses "go"

Tbe url generated is project/show, but it should be project/show/:id

not sure how to do this.

(Rails 5)

Comment: You’ll either need to perform a redirect response in the controller, and/or use Javascript to override the submit action on the form to go to the URL you want. Or maybe change the form to use `GET` instead of `POST` as the `method` and then have your routing handle `project/show?id=X`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that.  I decided to forget about trying to get it into the route, and instead just create an action called project/display and get the id out of the params hash.